# NSNumber decimal to C primitive value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber

I want to convert a decimal `NSNumber` to an `int` or other form which I can do math with. Here's the annotated code for my project:

```
NSNumber *Left = [left valueForOutputKey:@"Y"];
```

This line gets a Quartz Composer Outlet, usually with a value around 0.512.

Basically, I want to multiply this by 10, and then do some operations like greater than and less than to see which range it is in.

Comment: `[Left intValue]` (See the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: If the value is 0.512 you want a float or double, not an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks like you're dealing with a fractional component, you want to convert it to a float or a double to perform your operations, depending on how big you expect that value to be. A float should be fine unless you're dealing with ridiculously large or precise numbers. Here's how it would look, for example:

```
float lValue = [[left valueForOutputKey:@"Y"] floatValue];

lValue *= 10;

if (lValue < 10) {
    // do whatever
}
else if (lValue > 50) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Then to store the value back in your outlet or whatever, you pack it back into a NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *newValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:lValue];

[left setValue:newValue forKey:@"Y"];
```

You may have to convert newValue into a string to display it in a control, just use [newValue stringValue] to do that.

Comment: Don't forget to divide it by 10 before you store it back, or you will find the number getting exponentially larger.

Comment: Right -- that's just filler code based on what he was asking.

Comment: Thanks - this has been a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the methods of `NSNumber`:

```
int leftInt = [Left intValue];
float leftFloat = [Left floatValue];
double leftDouble = [Left doubleValue];
```

Comment: Fair point, sorry. Anyway it's fine as a way "to convert a decimal NSNumber to an int".

Comment: Thanks - I have integrated this into my system :)